# Imported points from CSV file (latitude, latitude) don't show up in a post code shapefile

Tags: qgis

I can produce a point vector layer by importing latitude and longitude info from a CSV file in a new project.

After saving this file as an ESRI shapefile I can import it in a Postal Code shapefile. However now, the points don't show up. The same happens if I import the CSV file immediately in the project with the postal code shapefile.

I probably do something elementary wrong. Can some one help me out?

My aim is to show locations of interest on this postalcode file.

Comment: If you have 2 files you need to join them based on a common attribute - you can then save the joined file to a new shapefile will all the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Has the Postal Code shapefile the same CRS as the shapefile with the imported data?
If not, you have to reproject one of the shapefiles to do a clean import.

Or, switch the Postal code layer into editing mode, activate the imported layer, mark the imported points by rectangle, copy the objects with Edit/copy, switch to the postal code layer, insert them with Edit/paste, and save the edits.

You can control the action by deactivating the import layer.